# Need to do a custom save as for file with a date function and name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will save my worksheet with the title "EMM POS Breaks TD *last Business day*.... so for instance today I would need it to save as "EMM POS Breaks TD 10.01.15" ... I found some code online and it is saving properly and the date function is working, but it is not saving the workbook as an excel file.  Can anyone please shed some light on what I can do?  Thanks!

```
'x = Weekday(Today, vbSunday)
'Select Case x
'    Case 1
'        x = 2
'    Case 2
'        x = 3
'    Case Else
'    x = 1
'End Select
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="EMM Position Breaks TD " & _
'    Format(Date - x, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " ", FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", _
'    WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the .xlsx tail to your name.

Comment: Scott, thanks for getting back so quickly man.... This may sound dumb but where exactly am I putting the .xlsx? n

Comment: after this `Format(Date - x, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " "` put `& ".xlsx"` before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

To save the file as an ***.xlsx**, you need to indicate the `FileFormat` as *`xlOpenXMLWorkbook`*:

```
x = Weekday(Today, vbSunday)
Select Case x
    Case 1
        x = 2
    Case 2
        x = 3
    Case Else
    x = 1
End Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="EMM Position Breaks TD " & _
    Format(Date - x, "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", _
    WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

And as for the extension, you may just append it as it is suggested in the comments: `Filename:="EMM Position Breaks TD " & Format(Date - x, "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".xlsx"`.

Comment: If you need to save as XLSM, use `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (to keep all macros, if you have them). See more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).

Comment: Any ideas on how to specify a folder?  It is located on my desktop and named CRR.  Can't figure out how to do the path...

Comment: @abiedermann Have you finally solved it? Looks like you needed to add the folder to the Filename, `Filename:="EMM Position Breaks TD "` => `Filename:=fldr & "EMM Position Breaks TD "`